# Headless Dictionary Service not working

Tags: jss, dictionary

I am using Sitecore Headless Services Server XM 18.0.0, and the Layout Service(like: /sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=) is working just fine. But when I tried to use the Dictionary Service I got this error message:

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:50900/sitecore/api/jss/dictionary/TestApp/en/?sc_apikey=<HereIsMyApiKey>'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'DictionaryService'."}
```

Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Globalization.dll is there in my bin folder.

DictionaryServiceController is in the config as an "allowedController".

My ApiKey setting is:

- CORS Origins: "*"
- Allowed Controllers: "Sitecore.LayoutService.Mvc.Controllers.LayoutServiceController;    Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Globalization.Controllers.DictionaryServiceController;"
- Impersonation User: "extranet\anonymous"

My app setting is:

```
<app name="TestApp" sitecorePath="/sitecore/content/Sitecore Headless/TestApp" dictionaryPath="/sitecore/content/Sitecore Headless/TestApp/Dictionary folder" inherits="defaults" patch:source="z.Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.config"/>
```

What am I missed here?

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you using?  I’m assuming 10.1 because of Headless 18.  Is the XP or XM topology installed?

Comment: 50900 is an odd port number.  Are you running Sitecore in local IIS or containers?

Comment: Yes its 10.1.2, and I'm running it locally on IIS Express.

Answer (score 0):

IIS Express is not supported for Sitecore development. If you’re comfortable with containers I’d suggest investing your time in that technology.  Otherwise you’ll need to setup Sitecore against IIS 10.

Excerpt from the Sitecore 10.1 installation guide:

[https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/~/media/3EAB338431A14882A24B95CD231280D4.ashx?date=20210302T151415](https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/%7E/media/3EAB338431A14882A24B95CD231280D4.ashx?date=20210302T151415)

#### 2.2. IIS requirements

Sitecore Experience Platform can be hosted on the following IIS versions:
• IIS 10.0

You must use the version of IIS that your operating system supports. For more information about IIS and operating systems, see Microsoft’s documentation.

**Sitecore Experience Platform does not officially support any other ASP.NET web servers such as IIS Express, or Mono Web Server.**
Sitecore Experience Platform neither supports nor allows multiple IIS website definitions to point to the same Sitecore web root.